# Bounding p-series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

It can be easily proven, $\forall p > 1$, that

$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^p} = \frac{1}{p-1}.$$

By the integral test of convergence for infinite series, this implies both that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges by the same condition for $p$, and that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p} > \frac{1}{p-1}.$$

This establishes a strict lower bound for all p-series with $p > 1$.

With this in mind, does there exist an upper bound for the p-series, such that

$$\frac{1}{p-1} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p} < f(p)$$

where $f(p)$ is some positive function of $p$?

Comment: You can make another picture where the p-series value lies below the curve $y=1/(x^p)$ and thus get an upper bound, similar to you the lower bound was found. There will be an initial part for the first term 1 of the p-series which then lies below the function between 0 and 1. You can't include that part in the integral or it will diverge, so you have to subtract the 1, then bound the rest, then add the 1 back for the upper bound.

Comment: @coffeemath I’ve done [this simulation on desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ccaxnbeug6), and it seems like the curve $f(x) = \frac1{x^p}$ is a lower bound for the sum (shown by the red rectangles).

Comment: As a hint, if $f : [1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is non-negative and non-increasing, then $$f(n+1) \leq \int_{n}^{n+1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \leq f(n). $$ Now sum this for $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ and see what this implies for the upper/lower bounds of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$.

Comment: @Mailbox Yes that does show a *lower bound* for the sum. I thought yur question was to find an upper bound for the sum. That can be done by redrawing your boxes (except for the first box of area 1) so they are all *under* the curve. Then you get that $1+1/(p-1)$ is an upper bound for the sum. Note this gives upper bound 2 for zeta function of 2 which is known to be $\pi^2/6,$ so it is working in that case as an upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @coffeemath for suggesting the visual proof of this.

So, the visual intuition for the integral test can be seen in the following image:

[image]

The area shown under the blue curve, $f(x)= \frac1{x^p}$, is $\frac1{p-1}$. Each rectangle has area $\frac1{n^p}$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, thus the sum of the red rectangles represents $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^p}$.

Since each rectangle is larger than the area underneath the curve bounded between it, this must mean that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^p} > \int\limits_1^\infty \frac{\text{d}x}{x^p} = \frac1{p-1}$.

Now, if ignore the first rectangle with area $1$, and shift each rectangle to the left by one unit, we get the following image:

[image]

Here, the sum of the rectangles represents $\frac1{2^p} + \frac1{3^p} + \frac1{4^p} + … = \left( \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^p} \right) - 1$, and they are clearly bounded below the same integral. Thus,

$$\left( \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^p} \right) - 1 < \frac1{p-1}
\\ \implies \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^p} < 1 + \frac1{p-1}  = \frac{p}{p-1}
$$

Therefore, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^p}$ is bounded below $\frac{p}{p-1} \, \forall p > 1$.